# Any better Fibonacci series generator using pure Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, algorithm, optimization, fibonacci

I wonder if there is any way to generate Fibonacci numbers that beat in simplicity and efficiency this one I wrote:

```
WITH d (seq) AS
       (SELECT     LEVEL
        FROM       DUAL
        CONNECT BY LEVEL < 195)
SELECT   seq
        ,fib
FROM     d
MODEL
  DIMENSION BY(seq)
  MEASURES(0 AS fib)
  RULES
    (fib [1] = 0,
    fib [2] = 1,
    fib [seq BETWEEN 3 AND 194] = fib[CV(seq) - 2] + fib[CV(seq) - 1],
    fib [seq > 194] = NULL)
ORDER BY 1
/
Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 2245903385

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                      | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT               |      |     1 |    13 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SQL MODEL ORDERED             |      |     1 |    13 |            |          |
|   2 |   VIEW                         |      |     1 |    13 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    CONNECT BY WITHOUT FILTERING|      |       |       |            |          |
|   4 |     FAST DUAL                  |      |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   3 - filter(LEVEL<195)


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          0  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
          0  consistent gets
          0  physical reads
          0  redo size
       4798  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
        500  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
         14  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          1  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
        194  rows processed

SQL>
```

Note: `LEVEL < 195` was not arbitrarily chosen, higher values make the algorithm lose precision so I decided not to include them in order to keep correct results only.

Comment: How are you defining simplicity and efficiency (specific metrics?), and which is more important? The simplest might not be most efficient, and vice versa.

Comment: I think a good answer should exceed in terms of readability and efficiency the original proposed, what do you think?

Comment: Readability is somewhat subjective. According to your comment on MTO's answer, you're just counting sorts. When I run your version inside a PL/SQL loop 1000 times it takes about 1.5 seconds; when I do the same with MTO's it takes about 0.7 seconds. (And mathguy's takes about 1.1 seconds). Your hardware etc. will make those numbers vary of course. So, what are you actually measuring to decide which is best?

Comment: @AlexPoole - I was starting to think... generating the powers in the hierarchical query will still make my query slow. Perhaps I need a better way to generate the powers... I'll suggest one way which you can test if you have written the test already.

Comment: There are several Oracle tools that reveal some internals related to the way the engine will solve the query. I'm using AUTOTRACE on SQLPlus. https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_eight.htm#SQPUG018

Comment: @AlexPoole - OK, I just posted a version that generates the powers in a different way. It would also be interesting to see how performance changes if we can remove the `ROUND()` call (if the OP needs the result to be correct only to, say, ten decimal places).

Comment: @mathguy - same rig, that version is about 1.2 seconds. (I'm running these repeatedly and they're fairly stable; also removing round doesn't seem to make a significant difference - it's actually very slightly *slower* for reasons I don't understand. And scaling up to 5000 iterations shows the same ratios between the approaches. 11.2.0.4/OEL 5/SQL Developer 4.2 *8-).

Comment: @AlexPoole - OK; it may be all the arithmetic operations that kill the "closed form" approach. Thank you for testing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

on the simplicity side of things, the query can rely on the built in features (`ITERATE ()` and `ITERATION_NUMBER`) of `MODEL`:

```
select * from dual
model
  dimension by (0 seq)
  measures (0 val)
  rules iterate (195) 
  (
     val[iteration_number] = val[iteration_number-1] + val[iteration_number-2],
     val[2] = 1, 
     val[1] = 0, 
     val[0] = 0
  )
;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a recursive sub-query factoring clause:

```
WITH fib ( lvl, value, next ) AS (
  SELECT 1, 0, 1
  FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
  SELECT lvl + 1, next, value + next
  FROM fib
  WHERE lvl < 195
)
SELECT lvl, value FROM fib
```

Comment: @jackattack Corrected

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I've autotraced it and it's more expensive (in terms of sorts)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should be (much?) faster:

```
with
     constants ( x, y, z ) as (
       select 0.5 * ( 1 + sqrt(5) ),
              0.5 * ( 1 - sqrt(5) ),
              sqrt(5)
       from   dual
     )
select level as seq, round( ( power(x, level - 1) - power(y, level - 1) ) / z ) as fib
from   constants
connect by level < 195
;
```

The point being, you don't need to use the recursive formula; the terms can be written in closed form. Since computers can't do arithmetic with real numbers, only with rational number approximations, I needed to add a `ROUND(...)` but even so this should be faster than recursive approaches.

**EDIT**: At the OP's request I traced the execution of this code. **I don't see the recursive calls** the OP is referring to in the Comment below.

```
Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1236776825

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name | Rows  | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |      |     1 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  CONNECT BY WITHOUT FILTERING|      |       |            |          |
|   2 |   FAST DUAL                  |      |     1 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(LEVEL<195)


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          0  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
          0  consistent gets
          0  physical reads
          0  redo size
       6306  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
        684  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
         14  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          1  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
        194  rows processed
```

**EDIT #2**

I suspect the simple generation of levels in a recursive query may be expensive. It's possible that a cross-join of similarly generated, but smaller sequences of integers may work a bit faster. The code looks more complicated (of course); the only change, though, is the way I generate the powers.

```
with
     constants ( x, y, z ) as (
       select 0.5 * ( 1 + sqrt(5) ),
              0.5 * ( 1 - sqrt(5) ),
              sqrt(5)
       from   dual
     ),
     powers ( n ) as (
       select 14 * a.p + b.q
       from   (select level - 1 p from dual connect by level <= 14) a
              cross join
              (select level - 1 q from dual connect by level <= 14) b
     )
select n + 1 as seq, round( ( power(x, n) - power(y, n) ) / z ) as fib
from   constants cross join powers
where  n < 195
;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think everybody here agrees a recursive formula is far away from an efficient way to solve this kind of problem, so there's no recursive approach in the original post. Trace your code and you'll see 2 recursive calls.

Comment: @jackattack - by "recursive formula" I meant "recursive formula", what does that have to do with "recursive **calls**"? I am talking about the math of it, with no reference to any code (SQL, C, FORTRAN or any other kind).

Comment: @jackattack - I posted the stats, I see no recursive calls. (Remember, that was off-topic anyway.)

Comment: stats you posted differ from those ones calculated in my place over your query, I see 2 recursive calls, but it's ok, it depends on several off-topic infrastructure parameters

Comment: Both of your approaches produce wrong results since 183rd term: yours: 48558529144435440119720805669229197640, correct: 48558529144435440119720805669229197641

Comment: @jackattack `recursive calls` and recursion (or as you put it recursive formula) are not the same. Recursive calls you see(only the first time you run the query) in your stat informs you about cache miss (query has to be hard parsed). In this case, you will see 0 recursive calls when you run the query second time. Flush the buffer cache or add a space in your query and you'll see those recursive calls again because the query has to be hard parsed again.

Comment: @jackattack - That's always the risk when doing non-integer arithmetic on a computer (as I did) - one of the disadvantages of the closed-form solution.